# Symfony2 + DoctrineMongoDBBundle Configuration

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to connect Symfony 2 with MongoDB in such way:

1. Register *DoctrineMongoDBBundle* in `AppKernel::registerBundles`
   method
2. Set '`doctrine_mongo_db`' configuration (see below `config.yml`)
3. Get '`doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager`' from container in
   `HelloController` action

And when I am trying to run the application *MongoConnectionException* is thrown.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

**AppKernel.php**

```
public function registerBundles()
{
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle(),
            new Sensio\HelloBundle\HelloBundle()
        );

        return $bundles;
    }
```

**config.yml**

```
framework:
    charset:       UTF-8
    router:        { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml" }
    templating:    { engines: ['twig'] } 

## Doctrine Configuration

doctrine_mongo_db:
    server: mongodb://root:root@192.168.0.111:27017
    default_database: test
    options: { connect: true }
    mappings:
        HelloBundle: { type: annotation, dir: Document }

# Twig Configuration

twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
```

**HelloController.php**

```
/* @var $dm \Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager */
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
```

**Exception (line 96)**

```
connecting to failed: Transport endpoint is not connected

in ~/vendor/doctrine-mongodb/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Connection.php line 96 »

93.    if ($this->server) {
94.        $this->mongo = new \Mongo($this->server, $this->options);
95.    } else {
96.        $this->mongo = new \Mongo();
97.    }
```

Comment: After some research I found that problem is in DoctrineMongoDBBundle::load method. The $configs should be merged before passed to DoctrineMongoDBBundle::doMongodbLoad method. It looks like a bug.

Comment: Yep, I was right. The guys are rewriting now DoctrineMongoDBBundle configuration. https://github.com/fabpot/symfony/pull/740

Comment: I think you should post that info as an answer and accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in DoctrineMongoDBBundle configuration loading. The fix (https://github.com/fabpot/symfony/pull/740) should be merged soon.

For now you can use fixed method below.

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $mergedConfig = array();
    foreach ($configs as $config) {
        $mergedConfig = array_merge_recursive($mergedConfig, $config);
    }

    $this->doMongodbLoad($mergedConfig, $container);
}
```